# Play sound when the app is background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

The app must to play a sound when it is in background. In the capabilities background fetch and audio & airplay are checked.

The method called for play the sound is that

```
-(void)playSound
{
NSString* str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alarm4" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];
NSError* erreur;

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&erreur];

if(!erreur)
{
    [self.audioPlayer setVolume:1];
    [self.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}

else
    NSLog(@"erreur de chargemnt %@", [erreur localizedDescription]);
}
```

Can you give me some advice, please?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is: Don't even dream of such a thing. In general, you can't do it.

You can *continue* playing a sound as you go into the background, but you cannot spontaneously *produce* a sound out of the blue in an *already* backgrounded app. It would be terrible if this could happen, because the user would not know where the sound is coming from, the sound could mess up the user's music listening experience, etc.

You should ask yourself why you think you need to do such a thing in the first place. You probably don't need to.

(Some Apple apps can do it. For example, the Clock app produces a repeating alarm sound out of the blue, in the background. But you, as you have probably noticed by now, are not Apple.)

Comment: everything was dark but now i see the light grace to your answer:  "you, as you have probably noticed by now, are not Apple". Thank you so much .

Comment: @Developer3000 You can try to produce an alarm sound as part of a UILocalNotification. That's legal because the system, not you, will actually be producing the sound when the notification "fires". But this also means that the user can turn off your sound. So it's a good solution, but not 100% reliable.

Comment: Naysayers. This is possible, it's just a lot harder than it should be. Can you give more information on when you want this to fire off?